# Throwing exception or fail the task using Future.failed

Tags: scala

I am using scala futures to poll API status . Continue to poll till return success or fail. How ever when any batch fails, it should throw error and stop the program.

I am not able throw error either by throw ( exception)  or Future.successful(false) or Future.failed(new Exception("error")) .

```
package FutureScheduler

import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


object delayTest extends App {

  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


  def getStatus(batchId: String): String = {
    print(s" $batchId ${System.currentTimeMillis()} continue \n")
    batchId match {
      case "batch1" => "success"
      case "batch2" => "failed"
      case "batch2" => "success" 
    }
  }


  def waitTask(batch: (String, Int)
              ): Future[Boolean] =
    Delayed(x.seconds)(getStatus(batch._1)).flatMap {
      case "success" =>
        print(s"\n${batch._1} succeeded for ${batch._2}")
        Future.successful(true)
      case "failed"  =>
        print(s"\n${batch._1} failed for ${batch._2}")
        Future.failed(new Exception("error"))
        throw new RuntimeException("errored")
      case _ => {
        waitTask(batch)
      }
    }


  val statusList =  List(Some("batch1", 123), None, Some("batch2", 124)).flatten

  val y = 1
  val x = 5

  try {
    Await.ready(Future.traverse(statusList)((waitTask _)), y.minutes)
  }
  catch {
    case e: Exception => println("caught error")
  }

  print("\nbye now")

}
```

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}

object Delayed {
  import java.util.{Timer, TimerTask}
  private val timer = new Timer
  def apply[T](delay: Duration)(task: => T): Future[T] = {
    val promise = Promise[T]()
    val tt = new TimerTask {
      override def run(): Unit = promise.success(task)
    }
    timer.schedule(tt, delay.toMillis)
    promise.future
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `Delayed` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `throw` is happening inside the `Future` returned by `Delayed` so it will be caught by that `Future`.

You need to turn `Await.ready` into `Await.result` and then look at the value that it returns to get the result of the test.